# Atualizar site WordPress usando uma versão paralela

Tags: wordpress, atualização

Tenho um site em Wordpress onde sofre atualizações constantes, tanto de layout como de plugins/funcionalidades.
Até ai normal, mas o que eu queria saber é se existe uma forma eficiente de atualizar o meu site como se fosse um site paralelo como segurança, para que ao atualizar as alterações não aparecessem no site.

Não sei se é a questão de copiar e colar o site, dentro de uma subpasta ou algo do tipo.

Preciso é atualizar o site (tema/codigo/plugins) e as alterações serem vistas em um "site" para depois de finalizadas e estando OK, serem passadas para o site ativo/online.
Não sei se fazer um CTRL+C CTRL+V do site ajudaria, mas assim ele iria alterar o banco de dados também.

Alguém tem uma idéia da melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que o seu caso seria necessário um ambiente de homologação, não? da pra fazer de vários jeitos... da uma olhada no vagrant, e em paralelo, [nesse tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/)

Comment: Dá uma estudada aqui: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment